# Buy One Get one Half off

Tags: cart, coupon

I have it set up so when a customer puts one item for group A in the cart and then an item from group b in the cart they would get a discount on the item from group b of 50%.

It works just fine.

Problem is, if the customer puts one item from group A and 2 items from group B then they would get the discount on both items from Group B.

I had to restrict it so the coupon only works once, but I really want the coupon to work multiple times, but on and one-to-one basis.  So item 1 from group A matches with Item 1 from group B but item 1 from group A does not match with item 2 from group B.  But Item 2 from group A matches to item 2 from group B

Would I need to limit it to Sku.  Like Sku 1 only matches with sku 2, but then that wouldn't work either because they still can't do multiples.

Any ideas short of hard coding this?

Thanks

Comment: I *think* this is not possible. You can add multiple rules every rule matching one quantity 1,2,3,4,5... to limit the discount...

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt. You should write it as an answer. Maybe with a small example.

Answer (score 1):

I **think** this is not possible. You can add multiple rules every rule matching one quantity 1,2,3,4,5... to limit the discount...

1. Define one rule: If cart contains quantity **1** products which are in the group (...) and give maximal **X** discount
2. Define second rule: If cart contains quantity **2** products which are in the group (...) and give maximal **2*X** discount

Comment: Correct: if you are using coupon codes you can only create 1 rule with the same code. This in turn means if you need multiple rules to achieve the outcome, you need to choose one or the other but not both.

Comment: Yes, @fabian is correct. I suggest you use a third party module like the Special Promotions Pro from Amasty (https://goo.gl/9WxbA4).